# how to sort vector of points based on X axis in opencv using c?

Tags: c, opencv

I detected edges in horizontal and vertical direction.I fill array of cordinates.Now I want merge them.  One contains data in ascending order:

```
(0,106),(0,107),(1,5),(1,6),(2,8)...
```

Another vector has points

```
(0,2),(0,5),(0,106),(0,107),(0,108),(1,6),(2,1)...
```

I want output as:

```
(0,2),(0,5),(0,106),(0,107),(0,108),(1,5),(1,6),(2,1),(2,8)
```

it not working properly.

Here is the code:

```
     #include "stdafx.h"

    #include <stdio.h>
    #include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
    #include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
    #include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <time.h>
    #include<fstream>

    using namespace cv;
    using namespace std;
    float *diffx2,*diffy1;

    int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
    {

    float   x1[1500],y1[1500],yy,xx,x2[1500],y2[1500];
    Point2f c,point;


    Mat img;


    float diffx1[250][250],diffy2[250][250];

    diffx2= new float[50000];
    diffy1=new float[50000];

    `img=cvLoadImage("C:\\Users\\abc\\Desktop\\opencv.png");



   imshow("Original image",img);
   cvtColor(img,img,CV_BGR2GRAY);
    imshow("gray img",img);
    printf("img rows=%d,img cols=%d",img.rows,img.cols);

Scalar intensity,nextx,currentx,prevx,nexty,prevy,currenty;

 /////////////for horizontal direction  ------>
int k=0;


for(int i=0;i<img.rows;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<img.cols;j++)
    {
        if(j==img.cols-1 )
            nextx=0;
        else
            nextx=img.at<uchar>(i,j+1);

        currentx=img.at<uchar>(i,j);


        if(j==0)
            prevx=0;
        else
            prevx=img.at<uchar>(i,j-1);

        diffx1[i][j]=(nextx.val[0]-currentx.val[0]);
        diffx2[k]=(nextx.val[0]+prevx.val[0]-2*(currentx.val[0]));
        k++;
    } 

    k=0;
int l=0;
for( int ii=0;ii<img.rows;ii++)
    for(int jj=0;jj<img.cols;jj++)
    {
        if((diffx2[k-1]>0 && diffx2[k+1]<=0) || (diffx2[k-1]<=0 && diffx2[k+1]>0))
            if(abs(diffx1[ii][jj])>0)
            {   
                x1[l]=ii;
                y1[l]=jj;
                l++;
            }
        k++;    
    }
int k1=0;
for(int i1=0;i1<img.rows ;i1++)
    for(int j1=0;j1<img.cols ;j1++)
    {
        if(i1==img.rows-1 )
            nexty=0;
        else
            nexty=img.at<uchar>(i1+1,j1);

        if(i1==0)
            prevy=0;
        else
            prevy=img.at<uchar>(i1-1,j1);

        currenty=img.at<uchar>(i1,j1);

        diffy1[k1]=(nexty.val[0]-currenty.val[0]);
        diffy2[i1][j1]=(nexty.val[0]+prevy.val[0]-2*(currenty.val[0]));
        k1++;
    }

    k1=0;
    int l1=0;
for( int ii=0;ii<img.rows ;ii++)
    for(int jj=0;jj<img.cols ;jj++)
    {

        if((diffy2[ii-1][jj]>0 && diffy2[ii+1][jj]<0) || (diffy2[ii-1][jj]<0 && diffy2[ii+1][jj]>0))
            if(abs(diffy1[k1])>0)
            {   
                x2[l1]=ii;
                y2[l1]=jj;
                l1++;
            }
            k1++;
    }

    float x3[2500], y3[2500];
    int ik = 0, kk = 0;
    int p1 = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int i = 0;
    for (int o = 0; o < l + l1;) {
        if (i < l && j < l1) {
            if (x1[i] == x2[j]) {
                if (y1[i] == y2[j]) {
                    x3[p1] = x1[i];
                    y3[p1] = y1[i];
                    p1++;
                    i++;
                    j++;
                } else if (y1[i] < y2[j]) {
                    x3[p1] = x1[i];
                    y3[p1] = y1[i];
                    p1++;
                    i++;
                } else {
                    x3[p1] = x2[j];
                    y3[p1] = y2[j];

                    p1++;
                    j++;
                }
            } else if (x1[i] < x2[j]) {
                x3[p1] = x1[i];
                y3[p1] = y1[i];
                p1++;
                i++;
            } else {
                x3[p1] = x2[j];
                y3[p1] = y2[j];
                p1++;
                j++;
            }
            o++;
        }
        if (i == l && j < l1) {
            x3[p1] = x2[j];
            y3[p1] = y2[j];
            p1++;
            j++;
            o++;
        }
        if (i < l && j == l1) {
            x3[p1] = x1[i];
            y3[p1] = y1[i];
            p1++;
            i++;
            o++;
        }
    }

        cvWaitKey();
        return 0;

    }
```

Comment: Do you want to merge two sorted sequences of points?

Comment: treat the first quantity of each point as an ID. Extract the points that have same ID and store them in a vector. Now use sort function for sorting each vector.

Comment: @shwetagupta - you originally tagged the post both [tag:c] and [tag:c++], and your title mentions c and OpenCV.  Solutions to your problem vary widely on which of these exactly you mean.  Also, the code sample you've provided is not complete *(cannot be run, no definition for `k` among other things...please see [the "MCVE" page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for how to include code)*.  There's no OpenCV in that code, so what's it for?

Comment: @shwetagupta Good that you found the edit button...but if you didn't find the Minimal Examples link to be clear enough on what is expected: read [this link about Short, Self Contained, Correct, Examples](http://sscce.org/).  We don't have a copy of `opencv.png` on our hard drives; and it's not clear that we should have to (or that the problem has anything to do with OpenCV at all).  Also: "it's not working" is insufficient; is it not compiling?  Are evil voices playing on the speaker instead of showing images?  How have *you* demonstrated that you're on the case with a good, minimal test?

Comment: i am getting output in my console application.But I am stuck in for loop somewhere.

Comment: you can download opencv logo from internet.216x233 opencv.png

Comment: @shwetagupta The point was to get you to think about what you need to do in order to get people to be willing to help you.  Is your problem only happening in a 216x233 file, or can you get the problem with one that is 10x10?  1x1?  If you are "stuck in a for loop somewhere" why aren't you under a debugger to be able to "break" and then tell where?  I don't want you to have a "bad" first experience of StackOverflow--it's very useful. BUT the goal is to inform you about what is expected of you to do *before* you ask a question.  So **read those links** I posted.  Several times. And try again.

Comment: please try to avoid opencv's deprecated c-api in general. it's no more developed/maintained, and a dead end. code like that should no more be written.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a bunch of points.

`(0,106), (10,111), (1,5), (1,2), (2,8), (5,2), (10,1), (0,109), (0,100), (9,106), (1,6), (2,1)`

You want to sort them in an ascending order, therefore the result should be

`(0,100) ,(0,106) ,(0,109) ,(1,2) ,(1,5) ,(1,6) ,(2,1) ,(2,8) ,(5,2) ,(9,106) ,(10,1) ,(10,111)`

Store your data in `vector<Point>` and use `sort2Dpoints()`. This is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

class Point
{
public:
    Point(int x, int y) : m_x(x), m_y(y)
    {}
    int m_x, m_y;
};



class PointStore
{
public:
    PointStore (int id) : m_id(id)
    {
    }
    int m_id;
    void addY(int y )
    {
        vecY.push_back( y );
        std::sort (vecY.begin(), vecY.begin()+vecY.size() );
    }
    int  getID() { return m_id; };
    std::vector<int> vecY;

};


std::vector< Point* > sort2Dpoints( const std::vector<Point>& vec )
{
    std::vector< PointStore* > storage;


    for ( int i(0); i < vec.size(); ++i ){
        int tempID = vec[i].m_x;

        if ( i == 0 ){
            storage.push_back( new PointStore(tempID) );
            storage[i]->addY( vec[i].m_y );
        }else{
            ////////////////////////////////////////////////
            bool isNew = true;

            for ( int j(0); j < storage.size(); ++j ){
                if ( tempID == storage[j]->getID() ){
                    isNew = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if ( isNew ){
                storage.push_back( new PointStore(tempID) );

                for (int k(0); k < storage.size(); ++k ){
                    if ( tempID == storage[k]->getID() )
                        storage[k]->addY( vec[i].m_y );

                }

            }else{


                for (int k(0); k < storage.size(); ++k ){
                    if ( tempID == storage[k]->getID() )
                        storage[k]->addY( vec[i].m_y );

                }

            }


        }////////////////////////////////////////////////
    }

    std::vector<int> vecID;

    for ( int i(0); i < storage.size(); ++i) {

        int tempID = storage[i]->getID();

        std::vector<int>::iterator it;

        it = find (vecID.begin(), vecID.end(), tempID);
        if ( !(it != vecID.end()) )
            vecID.push_back( tempID );


    }

    std::sort (vecID.begin(), vecID.begin()+vecID.size() );


    std::vector< Point* > sortedPoints;

    for (int i(0); i < vecID.size(); ++i ){
        for ( int j(0); j < storage.size(); ++j ){
            if ( vecID[i] == storage[j]->getID() ){
                for ( int k(0); k < storage[j]->vecY.size(); ++k )
                    sortedPoints.push_back( new Point (vecID[i], storage[j]->vecY[k] ) );

            }
        }
    }


    return sortedPoints;
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {


    Point p1(0,106),            // (0 ,106), (0,100), (0,109)
          p2(10,111),           // (1 ,  2), (1,  5), (1,  6)
          p3(1,5),              // (2 ,  1), (2,  8)
          p4(1,2),              // (5 ,  2)
          p5(2,8),              // (9 ,106)
          p6(5,2),              // (10,  1), (10,111)
          p7(10,1),
          p8(0,109),
          p9(0,100),
          p10(9,106),
          p11(1,6),
          p12(2,1);

    std::vector<Point> vec;
    vec.push_back( p1 );
    vec.push_back( p2 );
    vec.push_back( p3 );
    vec.push_back( p4 );
    vec.push_back( p5 );
    vec.push_back( p6 );
    vec.push_back( p7 );
    vec.push_back( p8 );
    vec.push_back( p9 );
    vec.push_back( p10 );
    vec.push_back( p11 );
    vec.push_back( p12 );


    for ( int i(0); i < vec.size(); ++i) {
            std::cout << "(" << vec[i].m_x << "," << vec[i].m_y << "), ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::vector< Point* > sortedPoints = sort2Dpoints( vec );


    for ( int i(0); i < sortedPoints.size(); ++i )
        std::cout << "(" << sortedPoints[i]->m_x << "," << sortedPoints[i]->m_y << ") ,";

    std::cout << std::endl;



    return 0;
}
```

In case you don't know how many points, then use `vector< Point* >` and change the code accordingly.